# Text file creation with some information and then data set in R

Tags: r, optimization, export

I want to link the writeLines and write.table for the creation of my specific data input file of Hydrological Model. here are the codes. I also want to show jus RootDepth Columan name at the end of all variables but it mus be blank.
i also will work on it because i will enter the values in specific row in Prec and will provide the rRoot values.

`txt <- "Pcp_File_Version=4\n*** BLOCK I: ATMOSPHERIC INFORMATION`

```
**********************************
\nMaxAL                    (MaxAL = number of atmospheric data-records)
\n116\nDailyVar  SinusVar  lLay  lBCCycles lInterc lDummy  lDummy  lDummy  lDummy  lDummy
\nf       f       f       f       f       f       f       f       f       f
\nhCritS                 (max. allowed pressure head at the soil surface)
\n0"
writeLines(txt, "ATMOSPH.txt")
#file.show("ATMOSPH.txt")

ATMOSPH<-data.frame(tAtm, Prec, rSoil, rRoot, hCritA, rB, hB, hT, RootDepth)
tAtm<-c(1:30)
Prec<-rep(0, 30)
rSoil<-rep(0, 30)
rRoot<-rep(0, 30)
hCritA<-rep(10000, 30)
rB<-rep(0, 30)
hB<- rep(0, 30)
hT<-rep(0, 30)
#RootDepth<-()
#write.table("ATMOSPH")
write.table(ATMOSPH, "G:/Rlearning/ATMOSPH.txt", row.name=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here and what does it have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I removed the `rails` tag, as there is no mention of it in the question.

Comment: I want to create a text file. first it write the text as first code show, then it write the table and show all the data.

Comment: everything must be according to its position because its an input file for model. It will be for thousands of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by opening a file connection that allows appending:

```
fileConn <- file("ATMOSPH.txt", open="a")

txt <- "Pcp_File_Version=4\n*** BLOCK I: ATMOSPHERIC INFORMATION**********************************
\nMaxAL                    (MaxAL = number of atmospheric data-records)
\n116\nDailyVar  SinusVar  lLay  lBCCycles lInterc lDummy  lDummy  lDummy 
lDummy  lDummy
\nf       f       f       f       f       f       f       f       f       f
\nhCritS                 (max. allowed pressure head at the soil surface)
\n0"

writeLines(txt, con = fileConn)
```

Then after building the ATMOSPH data frame, add it to the file like this:

```
write.table(ATMOSPH, file = fileConn, row.name=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

And don't neglect to close the connection:

```
close(fileConn)
```

Comment: Thank you Dear, Thank you very much. it works, But have one question here, I have one variable, the last column in data.frame and RootDepth, I just want to mention its name and all the column values blanks. thanks

Comment: @Moshin Waqas I think you want `RootDepth <- rep("", 30)` in the data.frame specification? That will give a blank column. Also, I think you are supposed to mark my answer correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have one more issue Dear, In Prec column, I want to enter some values in specific column. I entered the zero values, But whenever rainfall will occurs, I will enter the values in this txt file before running the model.

Comment: Please check my question one. I edited it. thanks. I think you can solve it easily. I am just new learner of R, I never audited a course on R.